# How to disable lints for the "bin" target only

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust project folder structure that contains an executable and a shared C-compatible library that are both build using the same sources. The `Cargo.toml` manifest file looks like:

```
[package]
name = "foo-bar"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ...

[lib]
name = "foo_bar"
crate-type = ["rlib", "cdylib"]

[[bin]]
name = "foo-bar"
test = false
doc = false

[dependencies]
...
```

As the executable is not using all of the code I get some "unused code" warnings when building the project with `cargo build`. I could add `#[allow(dead_code)]` lints all over my source code where necessary but that would disable them also when building the library target.

Is there a way to globally disable the "dead_code" lint only when compiling the (feature-wise smaller) `bin` executable target but having it enabled for the `lib` target?

Comment: What if you add `#![allow(dead_code)]` at the begining of your bin project?

Comment: That just does does the trick! I had assumed that it would only disable the lint for the current file (main.rs), but apparently it also applies to all included files. @FrenchBoiethios Please add an answer with the solution so I can mark it as  accepted.

Comment: How are you using the library from your executable? You _shouldn't_ be getting dead code warnings for items in your library if you reference it via `extern crate`.

Comment: As both targets live within the same directory I just include the needed modules and traits via `mod foo; use crate::foo::FooBar` into `main.rs`. The `lib.rs` file contains only publishing functions for the C-style library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can modify a lint for a whole crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/levels.html#via-an-attribute) by putting an attribute with `#!` at the beginning of the crate:

**main.rs:**

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

// etc.
```